# NopCommerce compare string with greek phrases

Tags: nopcommerce

I use Nopcommerce 3.5 and I need to compare a string coming from database (groupList[0].SpecificationAttributeName) with a greek phrase inside the .cshtml file, but it fails. I have tried string.Equals(string), string.Equals(string, StringComparison), string.IndexOf but all failed. The comparison between two english words succedes though. Do you know any solution on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your compare  string code with original data means your phrases so i can evaluate?

Comment: Thank you, here you are:  @if (string.Equals(groupList[0].SpecificationAttributeName, "Πλάτος Ελαστικού", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

Comment: Can you also give string.Equals(groupList[0].SpecificationAttributeName 's Value means on run time what is value in this..?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get this because it is running on production iis. Is there a way to get this? If I try to print it on screen through .cshtml, then I get "Πλάτος Ελαστικού" .

Comment: I just tested in my dev machine and it works. However, in production server still fails....

Comment: same happens in my system it's works fine........